# Exclude column in where clause if field value is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, web

I have a stored procedure for search screen where I have 5 different filters.
Users can leave the filters empty or have one filter and click on search button.

All the data is coming from database, I am trying to create stored procedure which can exclude columns in where clause if the parameter value is empty string.

```
@Id as nvarchar(256) = 1
@blnIsinProgress bit = 0
@strStatus varchar(20) = ''
@strName varchar(50) = ''
@strConfirmationNumber varchar(50)  = 123
@dtmSubmittedFrom Date = '12/31/9999'
@dtmSubmittedTo Date = '12/31/9999'
as
BEGIN
SELECT *
  FROM tblTable
  WHERE
    (@Id IS NULL OR lngID = @Id) AND
    (@blnIsinProgress IS NULL OR blnIsinProgress = @blnIsinProgress) AND
    (@strStatus = '' OR strStatus = @strStatus) AND
    (@strName= '' OR    strName= @strName) AND
    (@strConfirmationNumber = '' or @strConfirmationNumber = @strConfirmationNumber )
   End
```

But

```
Execute spManage 1,0,'','',123
```

will give me all the results

Comment: But the value of parameters is coming as empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
(@strConfirmationNumber = '' or @strConfirmationNumber = @strConfirmationNumber )
```

The second condition is always true.  You have an extra `@`.  So, try this:

```
(@strConfirmationNumber = '' or @strConfirmationNumber = strConfirmationNumber )
```